# Spring mongodb compass missing created data/collections

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I Save my data to database using spring.

```
   @RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "operators", path = "operators")
public interface OperatorsRepository extends MongoRepository<Operator, String> {
}
```

and I have file:

> main\resources\application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://admin:password@myclusterurl/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

In my config class I use:

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(OperatorsRepository operatorsRepository){operatorsRepository.save(myobjToSave);}
```

Everything works fine, i get data saved data using REST. But my problem is that in compass mongodb I don't see created collections and data. Why? Using mongo shell and mongo atlas is the same.

Comment: What is the code you are using to save the document in a collection?

Comment: Are you sure you have the data saved? Maybe try adding another REST endpoint that would fetch the data from database and then make sure you actually got it saved. With mongoDB clients there might be issues with data refreshment but I'm sure you have tried disconnect and reconnect again...

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a bean doesn't mean it is automatically executed. If you want to create a new collection from, let's say, a JSON file from the `src/main/resources` (or `test`), then you have to trigger the call of this method somehow.

I suggest to use `@PostConstruct` annotation that triggers once upon the object creation. Since you want to create data using the `OperatorsRepository`, I'd use it at `@Service` class injecting that object:

```
@PostConstruct
void createData() {
    this.operatorsRepository.save(myobjToSave);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```