# Search on Mongo Repositories using Criteria Query with MongoTemplate not working correctly in Mongo+springBoot app

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregate, criteria, mongotemplate

in this app I'm doing I also inserted a feature that allows me to look for specific items inside my objects of my Database repositories. For that, I used mongo template.
Every object in my repository gets compounded of the following items:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5f759b198dfb247ccd6280b2",
        "name": "Probando lo que cree",
        "text": "Enrique Gordon",
        "description": "Un poquito de todo ",
        "images": [
            "R0lGODlhLAEsAff"
        ],
        "videos": [
            "AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29"
        ],
        "date": null,
        "allComments": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5f759d2b8dfb247ccd6280ba",
        "name": "Probando lo que cree",
        "text": "Enrique Gordon",
        "description": "Algo nuevo",
        "images": [
            "R0lGODlhLAEsAff"
        ],
        "videos": [
            "AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29"
        ],
        "date": null,
        "allComments": null
    },
    {
        "id": "5f75a5e2275d7d34914d2d98",
        "name": "Zamorano",
        "text": "Zamorano",
        "description": "Zamorano",
        "images": [
            "iVBORw0KGgoAAAA",
            "/9j/4T/+RXhpZgA"
        ],
        "videos": [
            "AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29"
        ],
        "date": null,
        "allComments": null
    }
]
```

Thus having this in mind I initialized in my repository a function which returns a query bearing with the items : description, text, and name

```
REPOSITORY

   public List<Post> searchPosts(String search){

         return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(
                 Aggregation.match(new Criteria().orOperator(

                         Criteria.where("text").regex(search),
                         Criteria.where("description").regex(search),
                         Criteria.where("name").regex(search),
                         
                 ))
         ),"Post",Post.class).getMappedResults();
    }

*The post is the class already initialized with getters and setters, having in mind the concepts text, name , and description too
```

Then on my end point having in mind that criteria I pass whatever it brings as a path variable to my end point

```
CONTROLLER

    @GetMapping("/post/{search}/search")
    public List<Post> getSearchedPosts(@PathVariable ("search") String search){
        return postRepository.searchPosts(search);
    }
```

But for any reason when I bring to test the process in the postman, it brings me all the objects, but not the queried one.

Am I omitting something in the java query function?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need aggregation for this.

Try this - Hope this would work.

```
Query query= new Query(
        new Criteria()
        .orOperator(
            Criteria.where("text").regex(search),
            Criteria.where("description").regex(search),
            Criteria.where("name").regex(search)
        )
    );

return mongoTemplate.find(query, Post.class);
```

I have tried this on my local env with the sample documents you provided. I used `Zamorano` as search string. I am getting only one result. Here is my code -

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SOController {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/post/{search}/search")
    public List<Post> getSearchedPosts(@PathVariable("search") String search) {
        Query query = new Query(
                new Criteria()
                        .orOperator(
                                Criteria.where("text").regex(search),
                                Criteria.where("description").regex(search),
                                Criteria.where("name").regex(search)
                        )
        );

        return mongoTemplate.find(query, Post.class, "so");
    }
}
```

And this is img from postman -

[image]

**PS - Make sure your imports are correct.**

Comment: Thanks for your support wak786, but keeps acting the same

Comment: okay.. Based on the documents you posted. Can you provide some sample search strings that i can try with?

Comment: the array of objects i posted at the very beggining is good for that

Comment: in there all the data exposed gets along with the repository and controller classes

Comment: I am asking for examples of `search` string passed in this method. `postRepository.searchPosts(search)`

Comment: this is my end point loking for the world "zamorano " in that array of objects:"http://localhost:9000/portafolio/version1/post/Zamorano/search"

Comment: where the first " 'http://localhost:9000/portafolio/version1/'", belongs to the request made from front end angular

Comment: Its working fine for me. I am updating the answer with my code. Can you cross check or may be post your updated code?

Comment: literally something is going on , cause still keeps the same , perhaps does have to do something with this issue i also have so similar to this guy's one :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602119/spring-mongodb-compass-missing-created-data-collections

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222418/discussion-between-wak786-and-enrique-gf).